# Regex to spot characters

Tags: c#, regex

Please advise how to get the regex below: I would like to change the word in front of the ".abc_" to john. The word in front can be of any character long.

```
 material.abc_Inventory    = john.abc_Inventory  
 abx.abc_abxx              = john.abc_abxx  
 stackoverflow.abc_stack   = john.abc_stack
```

I am able to change if it has the fix character long but not this random word. Please advise

------- Edit below ------
Miss out the requirement below. The regex suggested on below solution highlighted all the text before the keyword including the "insert into" which i do not want.

```
insert into material.abc_Inventory   = insert into john.abc_Inventory  
insert into material.ABC_Inventory   = insert into john.ABC_Inventory
```

Comment: `(.*)\.abc_` should match your replace target.

Comment: @bdares your regex returns me all the "insert into ..". how do i match only the material.abc_ or material.ABC_

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without a regex, should be simpler and faster:

```
var str = "material.abc_Inventory";

str = "john" + str.Substring(str.IndexOf(".abc_"));

// str == "john.abc_Inventory"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("material.abc_Inventory", "^[^.]*[.]abc_", "john.abc_"));
```

This expression does not let the string preceding the `.abc_` contain a dot. If you would like to allow the dot, use `"^.*?\[.\]abc_"` instead ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/hfTAb)).

**EDIT:** If you must avoid spaces, use a different expression ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/wBJPr)):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("material.abc_Inventory", "^[^. ]*[.]abc_", "john.abc_"));
```

Now the list of consecutive characters in front of the keyword excludes spaces as well.